# Создать картинку из блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Возникла необходимость создать картинку из блока с картинкой и блока, который лежит поверх самой картинки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать на js/jquery? Вопрос - как сгенерить картинку, в которой будет сама картинка в img, а также зеленый квадрат?

```css
    .image-block {
        background: red;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        width: 1490px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    .another-blocks {
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .block {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        display: block;
    }
    .block2 {
        background: blue;
        display: rgb(0,255,0);
    }
    .block3 {
        background: green;
        display: rgb(0,255,0);
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 340px;
        z-index: 5;
     }
     .block4 {
        background: black;
        display: rgb(0,255,0);
     }
     .block1 {
        background: red;
        display: rgb(0,255,0);
     }
```

```html
    <div class="image-block">
     <img src="https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/dde/292/490/dde292490b55a8c0824ecc6cc038f999.png" alt="картинка" width="1490" height="400">
     <div class="block block3"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="another-blocks">
     <div class="block block1"></div>
     <div class="block block2"></div>  
     <div class="block block4"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, желательно с примером. Сейчас что-то вообще непонятно...

Comment: @Cheg понял, будет сделано :)

Comment: @Cheg изменил вопрос

Comment: Т.е. на выходе вам нужно получить jpg или png с таким изображение как у вас в верстке? Или я вообще ничего не понял?)

Comment: @Cheg да, все правильно) затем будет реализовано, чтобы человек посредством drag-n-drop перемещал блоки, а затем все это будет конвертиться в изображение.

Comment: @Cheg но пока не пойму, каким образом конвертить изображение, смысла о последующих действиях говорить нет, поскольку костылей могу очень много наделать

Comment: Тут простым js/jquery не обойтись. Для этого нужны специальные библиотеки. К сожалению, в этом вопросе я некомпетентен(

Comment: @Cheg вот-вот, поэтому и в ступоре, как это люди делают. Столько сайтов-редакторов изображений, а тут просто блок перетащить и картинку сохранить надо

Comment: я делал такое, под рукой нету, но кажется накладывал на нужный блок canvas и его уже брал